# Remember me Checkbox in android studio

Tags: android

New to Coding and Android Studio.I am trying to set Remember me function in my app but everytime something gets wrong. Here is my code. I tried using sharedpref but did not succeed.somebody help me with this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    TextInputLayout Tmail,Tpass;
    ProgressBar Bar;
    CheckBox checkbox;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        Tmail = findViewById(R.id.login_email);
        Tpass = findViewById(R.id.login_password);
        Bar = findViewById(R.id.bar);
        checkbox = findViewById(R.id.remember);

    }

    public void signhere(View view) {
        Bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String email = Tmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String password = Tpass.getEditText().getText().toString();
        

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Tmail.getEditText().setText("");
                            Tpass.getEditText().setText("");
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "login Succesful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,profile.class));
                            finish();

                        } else {
                            Bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Check Email/Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CheckBox saveLoginCheckBox; // Remember me check box
    private SharedPreferences loginPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;
    private Boolean saveLogin;

    saveLoginCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.saveLoginCheckBox);
    loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();

    saveLogin = loginPreferences.getBoolean("saveLogin", false);
        if (saveLogin == true) {
        editTextUsername.setText(loginPreferences.getString("username", ""));
        editTextPassword.setText(loginPreferences.getString("password", ""));
        saveLoginCheckBox.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this code in `addOnCompleteListener` method:

```
if (saveLoginCheckBox.isChecked()) {
            loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("saveLogin", true);
            loginPrefsEditor.putString("username", username);
            loginPrefsEditor.putString("password", password);
            loginPrefsEditor.commit();
        } else {
            loginPrefsEditor.clear();
            loginPrefsEditor.commit();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it.

Comment: Sorry, I already tried but due to less reputation it doesn't allow me to vote.